# Angular - Reload / Update component data after being redirected from another component while using query parameters

Tags: angular, query-string, ngoninit

I'm working with 2 components. `MyNotesComponent` and `CourseToolsComponent`.

In `CourseToolsComponent` I add a new note and show recent notes as well, as shown below.
[image]

When I click on any of the note (as show in image "Note 1, Note 2 or Note 3"). I have the following function on Clicking of the note in CourseToolsComponent.

```
directToNote(id){
     this.router.navigate(['/student/my-notes'], {queryParams: {"notes": id}})
    }
```

This directs me to /student/my-notes?notes=1

**Issue:**
If I open the `MyNotesComponent` directly, it shows me the fetched notes data correctly. After viewing that data I go to the `CourseToolsComponent` to **add a new note and click on newly added note it redirects me to `MyNotesComponent` page but the Data is not updated on `MyNotesComponent` with the latest note added.** If I refresh the page then the data is updated and shown.
How can I refresh the data each time I navigate to `MyNotesComponent` ?

MyNotesComponent.ts

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this.fetchNotes();
}
 //Get All Notes 
  fetchNotes(){
    this.courseApi.coursesCourseNotesNotesList().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.notesSaved = data;
      },
      (err) => { console.error(err); },
      () => { }
    )
  }
```

**Things I've tried:**
-Adding routeReuseStrategy to router navigation from CourseToolsComponent as:

```
 directToNote(id){
            this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
              return false;
          }
           this.router.navigate(['/student/my-notes'], {queryParams: {"notes": id}})
          }
```

Doesn't work.
Also added routeReuseStrategy to constructor of `MyNotesComponent` it doesn't work at all.